# ODE arising from best constant for Sobolev Embedding

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I was trying to solve the critical exponent PDE 
$$\Delta u = u^\frac{n+2}{n-2}$$ 
in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and ultimately reduced it to the following ODE $$\frac{dy}{dr}=ce^{\int_0^r{y}}-y^2-\frac{y}{r}$$ 
with the initial condition $y(0)=k \in \mathbb{R}$ for any $n\geq 3$. I want to prove existence and uniqueness in $[0,\epsilon)$. I tried to do this for the simpler case 
$$\frac{dy}{dr}=1-y^2-\frac{y}{r}$$ 
but even here I don't know how to deal with the $1/r$. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Making the variable change

$$
y = \frac{z'}{z}\Rightarrow r z''+z'-r z = 0
$$

which is linear. All this for $r z \ne 0$

Comment: This is the ODE I started with. Can you solve it? Because the 1/r is there as well.

Comment: @AdityaKumar The solution is $y(r) = C_1 J_0(i r)+C_2 Y_0(-i r)$ (Bessel functions)

Comment: Okay, but this won't work in the general case :(